# Real Analysis: Not sure if textbook proof is incomplete.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading Bartle's text (Real Analysis 4th edition), pg 42.

The following proof seems incomplete. The conclusion that he makes in the last sentence seems to be a leap of logic.

For example, how does he know that $1/n_t$ is actually less than $t$? Couldn't it be greater than $t$?

On a different note, is this a good book to use to learn this subject? I am new to proofs and real analysis.

[image: Proof]

Comment: I'm curious to see the theorem that preceded this corollary.

Comment: https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf

Comment: It might be helpful for you to recall the definition of the infimum---the final line is a direct application of that definition.

Comment: Xander, thank you. This is in line with John's comment.

Answer (score 4):

Becuase notice that $0$ is the infimum which is the greatest lower bound, meaning that any number greater than $0$, say $t >0$ for example ${\bf cannot}$ be a lower bound so there is some value in the set $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ that is between $0$ and $t$, in this case $n_t$ so that

$$ 0 < \frac{1}{n_t} < t $$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ...

Comment: @quantactuary I'm curious why you think this doesn't answer the question. It does.

Comment: Read the question that was asked.

Comment: @quantactuary You're not going to be able to learn with such an aggressive attitude toward those trying to help you.

Comment: I'm not being aggressive, just asking for a concrete answer. Simply restating the books answer is insufficient and unacceptable.

Comment: @quantactuary: you need to ping people using "@" followed by the username. I just happened to come back and read that you had responded to my comment, but if you ping a user, they'll be notified automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to proofs, you might want to try:

> Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis (by Geoff Smith)

The proof is complete as it is. This is a matter of quantification.
If you were to pick an arbitrary number $n \in \mathbb N$, then of course you cannot say that $1/n < t$. However, this proof shows that *there exists* an $n_t \in \mathbb N$ such that $1/n_t < t$. If you take another look at the definition of lower bounds, this should become clear.

Comment: Sorry, but no evidence has been shown for "Thus, there exists ... ". If there is a reason, it should be provided concretely.

Comment: @quantactuary We know that $t$ is not a lower bound for the set because $t\gt 0$. Therefore, there has to be an element of the set that is smaller than $t$.

Comment: John, thank you! Your second sentence refers to what was missing.